"i" button click triggers monument info popup (Frontend Help)
I'm working on a college (mini) project tourism website for booking trips and showcasing monuments in India. There are some buttons on the index page which on clicking redirects the user to a different page which has boxes containing a monument image, it location and a book now button. I want to add "i" buttons to each monument box that appears when u hover over the box which when clicked, displays a popup with information related to that monument like history, culture, and tradition.
I have the monument information stored in a JSON file (monuments.json). I'm using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript for the frontend.
My question is: How can I achieve the click functionality for the "i" button to trigger the popup display with monument information fetched from the JSON file?
ill paste one of the files where i have to achieve tis functionality.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Tourism Website
</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-                      

  awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
<section class="packages" id="packages">
    <div class="box-container">
        <div class="box">
            <img src="images/north/agra fort.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="content">
                <h3><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"> Agra Fort</i></h3>
                <p>Agra</p>
                <div class="stars">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="price"> Rs. 45 <span> per adult</span></div>
                <a href="#book" class="btn">book now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="images/north/baijnath.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="content">
         <h3><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"> Baijnath Temple</   i></h3>
                <p>Himachal Pradesh</p>
                <div class="stars">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="price"> Rs. 35<span> per adult</span></div>
                <a href="#book" class="btn">book now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="images/north/chittaurgarh.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="content">
          <h3><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"> Chittaurgarh Fort</i></h3>
                <p>Chittorgarh</p>
                <div class="stars">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="price"> Rs. 35<span> per adult</span></div>
                <a href="#book" class="btn">book now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="images/north/dhamek.jpeg" alt="">
            <div class="content">
             <h3><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"> Dhamekh Stupa</i></h3>
                <p>Sarnath</p>
                <div class="stars">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="price"> Rs. 35<span> per adult</span></div>
                <a href="#book" class="btn">book now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="images/north/humayun.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="content">
             <h3><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"> Humayun's Tomb</i></h3>
                <p>New Delhi</p>
                <div class="stars">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="price"> Rs. 35<span> per adult</span></div>
                <a href="#book" class="btn">book now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="images/north/jageshwar.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="content">
             <h3><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"> Jageshwar Dham</i></h3>
                <p>Uttarakhand</p>
                <div class="stars">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="price"> Rs. 35<span> per adult</span></div>
                <a href="#book" class="btn">book now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="images/north/jantar.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="content">
             <h3><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"> Jantar Mantar</i></h3>
                <p>New Delhi</p>
                <div class="stars">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="price"> Rs. 35<span> per adult</span></div>
                <a href="#book" class="btn">book now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="images/north/kulbhalgarh.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="content">
          <h3><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"> Kumbhalgarh Fort</i></h3>
                <p>Kumbhalgarh</p>
                <div class="stars">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="price"> Rs. 35<span> per adult</span></div>
                <a href="#book" class="btn">book now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="images/north/leh palace.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="content">
                <h3><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"> Leh Palace</i></h3>
                <p>Leh</p>
                <div class="stars">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="price"> Rs. 35<span> per adult</span></div>
                <a href="#book" class="btn">book now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="images/north/qutub minar.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="content">
                <h3><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"> Qutub Minar</i></h3>
                <p>New Delhi</p>
                <div class="stars">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="price"> Rs. 35<span> per adult</span></div>
                <a href="#book" class="btn">book now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="images/north/ranthambore.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="content">
           <h3><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"> Ranthambore Fort</i></h3>
                <p>Ranthambore</p>
                <div class="stars">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="price"> Rs. 0 (Free Entry)</div>
                <a href="#book" class="btn">book now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="images/north/red fort.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="content">
                <h3><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"> Red Fort</i></h3>
                <p>New Delhi</p>
                <div class="stars">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="price"> Rs. 35<span> per adult</span></div>
                <a href="#book" class="btn">book now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="images/north/sikri.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="content">
             <h3><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"> Fatehpur Sikri</i></h3>
                <p>Fatehpur Sikri</p>
                <div class="stars">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="price"> Rs. 35<span> per adult</span></div>
                <a href="#book" class="btn">book now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <img src="images/north/taj mahal.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="content">
                <h3><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"> Taj Mahal</i></h3>
                <p>Agra</p>
                <div class="stars">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="price"> Rs. 35<span> per adult</span></div>
                <a href="#book" class="btn">book now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
  </section>
 </body>

 </html>


what JSON file? where does it come from? please post your code as a [repro] paying extra attention to the words minimal!

Assuming by "i" button, you mean a button that shows the letter i and creates a popup or tooltip with the info you want to show, you'd create that with HTML.
You can either use a button element, or img, div, whatever. Then you'd handle the click via JavaScript (addEventListener('click', fn)). Whatever you use, you can also use CSS to style it so that the cursor appears as a pointer when the user mouses over it, to indicate that it is clickable:
.info-button: {
  cursor: pointer;
}

Part of designing such functionality will also require you to decide whether you want to dynamically create a popup via JavaScript or have one already existing within your HTML that just becomes updated and made visible via your JS when your "i" button is clicked.
You can use createElement() in JS to dynamically build, create and insert your element or, probably more simply in this case, have a single div that is hidden, and then shown on click. You can use absolute positioning and the top and left CSS properties to position a div at the mouse cursor position which is info you can get via the click event (the mouse X/Y position).
As for your JSON file, you probably want to use fetch to load the data and then use it accordingly:
fetch('./data.json')
   .then(response => {
       if (!response.ok) {
           throw new Error("Error " + response.status);
       }
       return response.json();
   })
   .then(json => {
       // do stuff here, e.g. store data for later access
   })
   .catch(err => {
       console.error(err);
   })

and once you have that data, show the relevant content when a user clicks your "i" button.
Additionally, you can store "extra data" on your "i" button elements so if your JSON has specific keys, you can store that there and access it when the element is clicked:
// example image as "button" 
<img src="i.png" data-id="agra-fort" class="info-btn"/>

// JS to handle click on button
document.querySelector(".info-btn").addEventListener("click", (event)=> {
  const id =  this.getAttribute("data-id");
  // show div
});

// jsonData[id];

This is a dataset property, and you can read more about it here.
Of course, since its school work, I've avoided giving any complete code for the scenario. That's for you to figure out!
So, to summarise:

HTML for the "i" button
HTML for the "popup" or "tooltip" info
JS to handle button click, update tooltip content and display tooltip


Thank you for helping me. Ill figure the rest out and let you know how well it worked. Have a great day!
